# How can I turn off the bags?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I recently [learned](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/120213/15095) that Not Enough Items has other features than allowing you to retrieve any block in the game. Needless to say, that's pretty awesome, and I now use it to help me learn the purpose of blocks I find or to remind me of recepies I've forgotten.  When I'm not using it for anything, I toggle off all of it's features so it doesn't clutter my screen up whenever I open my inventory or chest. Except even when I have everything toggled off, the Backpacks from the Forestry mod never go away. Am I doing something wrong? Why do these items persist when no others do?

This is before I toggle off the displays.

[image: All the stuff]

This is after I toggle off the displays.

[image: No stuff except bags]

Comment: What do you mean "Backpacks never go away?" Where do you no longer expect them to be? Maybe a screenshot would help?

Comment: i think he's talking about the NEI filtering system and he wants to filter out backpacks?

Comment: pressing O disables and hides all of NEI until you press it again.

Comment: Screenshot please.

Comment: Screenshots inbound. Prepare to copy...

Comment: Assuming nobody knows why this is specifically happening, @JLabella's comment about using O works even better than what I was doing, so if posted as an answer I'll gladly accept that.

Comment: That's really weird. My guess is the Forestry addon for NEI is buggy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you just wanted to hide NEI, Press O(deafult) to disable and hide all NEI features. Pressing it again brings it back up.

The reason the backpacks are remaining is probably a bug in communication between forestry and NEI (no item type, label, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if my particular issue is a bug or not, but it doesn't really matter much in the long run as...

> Pressing **O** toggles on or off the entire **Not Enough Items** display, which actually works even better than what I was doing in the first place.

Thanks to @JLaBella for this tip.

Comment: Also note that the grey menu list thingy that overlaps your armour slots is an optional thing you can turn off. I find it annoying and useless and in the way. With it off, I never found the need to turn off the rest of NEI's UI.